# "the layout could not be loaded: layout resource could not be found" xamarin android vs 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

everytime i create a new layout.axml i get the message

**the layout could not be loaded: layout resource could not be found**
[image: "the layout could not be loaded: layout resource could not be found"]

upon creation  and i am new to programming and dont know where to go or what to add to fix this problem and when googled i get very similar but different errors. ive tried rebuilding in attempt that it may create a resource file and didn't work. also tried updating the android sdk in sdk manager from a suggestion online and also did not work. im using vs 2019 in Xamarin

Comment: Try to run project once and see if it's make it work.

Comment: You can add some controls(such as button, textview) in this new layout, if Android UI Designer will reflash.